# Calculate max distance between two non-parallel lines using python

Tags: python, math, line

[image]I have two line segments with their coordinates:

```
l1:(x1,y1,x2,y2)
l2:(x3,y3,x4,y4)
```

How do i find the max distance between these two lines? i read through some math algorithms but they are too complicated and I could'nt understand. Is there any function that can be used in python?

Comment: Are your lines in the 2d plane? In that case, distance will depend on where you start on the lines, as non-parallel lines will cross (distance then is 0). If they are in 3d space, I don't understand the way you give their coordinates.

Comment: it is in 2d plane...and what does it mean when u say where i start?

Comment: Do you mean `l2:(x3,y3,x4,y4)`? Otherwise, these two lines are the same...

Comment: 2 non-parallel lines in the 2d plane will always cross. Therefore, the minimum distance between them is 0. If you want another type of distance (say from a point one one of the lines to the other line) that''s a different problem.

Comment: Also, do you mean line **segments** rather than (infinite) lines?

Comment: I do think that is what he means, and @hanuka_code please specify that they are in 2d plane in the question.

Comment: i just attached the image of the two lines, maybe it is clear now

Comment: They do not seem to be non parallel

Comment: Your diagram would have been more useful if it had also indicated the "max distance" you're trying to find.  The maximum possible distance is between the top point of the left line, and the bottom point of the right line (that's what @TimurShtatland 's answer gives you), but I can imagine other possible interpretations you might have intended.

Comment: thanks, but i need the distance between the top point of the left line to the top part of the right line..is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Compute the max distance between 2 line segments like so:

```
# L1: (x1, y1), (x2, y2)
# L2: (x3, y3), (x4, y4)

d13 = ((x1 - x3)**2 + (y1 - y3)**2)**0.5
d14 = ((x1 - x4)**2 + (y1 - y4)**2)**0.5
d23 = ((x2 - x3)**2 + (y2 - y3)**2)**0.5
d24 = ((x2 - x4)**2 + (y2 - y4)**2)**0.5

d_max = max([d13, d14, d23, d24])
```

Comment: But is it possible to find the distance between the top point of the left line to the top part of the right line?

Answer (score -1):

i think it is math problem.
I think you might mean line segment rather than line.
Because the max distance between two line is infinite.
So, if you mean line segment. You just need to calculate the slope of l2(s2), and make a new line l3 which have slope -1/s2. Then calculate the intercept of l3 which cross x1,y1 of l1 or x2,y2 of l1. Then calculate the distance like a math problem.

```
def dis(l1_x1,l1_y1,l1_x2,l1_y2,l2_x1,l2_y1,l2_x2,l2_y2):
    s2 = (l2_y2-l2_y1)/(l2_x2-l2_x1) #slope of l2
    i2 = l2_y2 - s2*l2_x2 #intercept of l2
    # calculate intercept of l3 by crossing l1 at x1,y1
    i3_1 = l1_y1-(-1/s2)*l1_x1 #intercept of l3
    s3_1 = -1/s2 #slope of l3
    # calculate the distance from x1,y1 of l1 to l2
    distance_x1 = (i2-i3_1)/(s3_1-s2)
    distance_y1 = s2*distance_x1 + i2
    distance_1 = np.sqrt((l1_x1-distance_x1)**2+(l1_y1-distance_y1)**2)
    # calculate intercept of l3 by crossing l1 at x2,y2
    i3_2 = l1_y2-(-1/s2)*l1_x2 #intercept of l3
    s3_2 = -1/s2 #slope of l3
    # calculate the distance from x2,y2 of l1 to l2
    distance_x2 = (i2-i3_2)/(s3_2-s2)
    distance_y2 = s2*distance_x1 + i2
    distance_2 = np.sqrt((l1_x2-distance_x2)**2+(l1_y2-distance_y2)**2)
    if distance_1 <= distance_2:
        return distance_2
    else:
        return distance_1
```

Comment: the distance you mean is vertical or two-point connection?

Comment: the distance between the top point of the left line to the top part of the right line.. so from point to point